# jquery ajax in codeigniter returns nothing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

this is my function in controller 
    function show_data()
    {
        return " this is me ";
    }

this is my view:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ajax call first time</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">                                               </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("hello");
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            dataType: "text", 
            url:'elements/show_data',
            success:function(res){
            console.log(res);
                $('#response').html(res);
            },
            fail:function()
            {
                $('#response').html("done");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="response" id="response" ></div>
<div class="container" id="container" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

the console says `empty string returned`  why?

Comment: Did you use something like Firebug to see what the AJAX sent and received?

Comment: the last line is response from firebug

Comment: i gotthe answer, i have to use echo in place of return

Comment: Only your controller action returns a string must not mean that it will return it to the browser as well. Please learn first how that framework is intended to work, follow the intention and then if this mismatches, wonder. Not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    url: 'the/url',
    data: {data1: "value", data2: "value"}
}).done(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

You may want to check your url `elements/show_data` with browser (use GET) to make sure that your controller works.